# Handling button click on a pdf using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I Have created a PDF using `ItextSharp` which contains `radio button` and a `button`.

I want to send the entire PDF to a service when the button is clicked,but not able to get how to handle the event. And also can someone please suggest me how to align the button to bottom left.

Code what I am using is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=Example.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
string pdfFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "/PDFFiles";
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
doc.Open();
doc.AddAuthor("Test author");
doc.AddCreationDate();
PdfContentByte cb = wri.DirectContent;
Font _bf = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6);
PdfFormField _radioGroup = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(wri, true);
_radioGroup.FieldName = "language_gc";
Rectangle _rect;
RadioCheckField _radioG;
PdfFormField _radioField1;
for (int i = 0; i < LANGUAGES_gc.Length; i++)
{
    _rect = new Rectangle(46, 806 - i * 40, 60, 788 - i * 40);
    _radioG = new RadioCheckField(wri, _rect, null, LANGUAGES_gc[i]);
    _radioG.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.8f);
    _radioG.BorderColor = GrayColor.BLACK;
    _radioG.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CIRCLE;
    _radioField1 = _radioG.RadioField;
    _radioGroup.AddKid(_radioField1);              

    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(LANGUAGES_gc[i], new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18)), 70, 790 - i * 40, 0);
}
/* Button */
_rect = new Rectangle(100, 806, 170, 788);
PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(wri, _rect, "Buttons");
button.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.75f);
button.BorderColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
button.BorderWidth = 1;
button.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED;
button.TextColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
button.FontSize = 12;
button.Text = "Submit";
button.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_LEFT_LABEL_RIGHT;
button.ScaleIcon = PushbuttonField.SCALE_ICON_ALWAYS;
button.ProportionalIcon = true;
button.IconHorizontalAdjustment = 0;
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
wri.AddAnnotation(_radioGroup);
wri.AddAnnotation(button.Field);
cb = wri.DirectContent;
doc.Close();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(doc);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: You say "I want to send the entire PDF to a service" but if you'd study all the documentation on this subject, you'd know that *submitting an entire PDF* is only possible if the end user has Adobe Acrobat (the paying version). What you ask is impossible if the end user only has Adobe Reader (the free version) or another PDF viewer. So the real question is: do your end users all have an Adobe Acrobat license?

Comment: Not with the same code, no, you'll need other code.